# Cannot Log Into phpMyAdmin - Nothing Happens

Tags: mysql, lamp

I'm running a simple LAMP server at home from which I host a personal blog. The server is running Arch Linux, with the latest-and-greatest versions of Apache, MySQL, and PHP. In order to easily maintain the databases, I installed phpMyAdmin. However, I cannot login. If I were to SSH into the server and run `mysql -u <user> -p <password>`, no errors show up and I'm immediately placed into the MySQL prompt. No problem.

However, when I try to log in with phpMyAdmin, using those exact same credentials, nothing happens. No errors, no nothing, I'm just redirected back to the login page.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: As per the [FAQs](http://serverfault.com/faq), Server Fault usually frowns upon questions in a home setting - the question would be better suited to SuperUser. That said, as a starting point check your php.ini settings for `session.save_path` (e.g. using phpinfo()) and ensure that path is writeable by the user PHP is running as (and check your server logs for errors).

Answer (score 2):

Installing the mcrypt php module solved the issue for me (apt-get install php5-mcrypt).

How I found the issue:

1. Set $cfg['Error_Handler']['display'] = true; in config.inc.php
2. Set authentication mode from cookie to http
3. Log in and see the error message that mcrypt is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same symptom with phpMyAdmin on a CentOS server. (Kept trying to log in but kept getting redirected to the login screen, without any error nor warning.) It turned out the webspace was simply out of space. Making some room fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you did the wrong configuration information. Let 's try to delete file config.inc.php and try again. In this case, it will ask you login as default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For those desperate like me, who spent hours searching a trying EVERY solution on the Internet. The problem wasn't with the permissions or ownership. I removed the "3;" from session.save_path = "3;/var/lib/php/sessions". That is the default value when you install apache2-php5.
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path):

> There is an optional N argument to this directive that determines the number of directory levels your session files will be spread around in. For example, setting to '5;/tmp' may end up creating a session file and location like /tmp/4/b/1/e/3/sess_... In order to use N you must create all of these directories before use.

After setting $cfg['Error_Handler']['display'] = true; in config.inc.php I could read the error: `session_start(): open(/var/lib/php/sessions/r/i/a/sess_blablabla, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory`

Also remember to set permission to the default 1773 (others also work: 0733, 0773, 0777)